# how to dictionary format to file?

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting, output

i have a

```
     d= {'fall':['basketball', 'hockey','football']
           'spring': ['cross country','tennis','baseball']
           'summer':['soccer', 'softball']
            etc....
```

I want to write it to a file. like the following.
            Sports play in fall:
            basketball
            hockey
            football
            Sports played in spring:
            cross country
            tennis
            baseball..

The code that i have written so far:

```
for n in range(len(sp)):
    print("Sports Played in",i)
    print(sp[i,'\n'])
```

i also want to reverse it to so
so it reads in alphabetic order:

baseball <a gap should be here> spring
    basketball <a gap should be here> fall
    cross country <a gap should be here> spring

The columns should line up.

```
def reverse_dict(dct):
    reverse = {}
    for key, vals in dct.items():
        for val in vals:
            if val not in reverse:
                reverse[val] = []
            reverse[val].append(key)
    return reverse

keys=list(reverse.keys())
keys.sort()
for x in keys:
    f1out.write("".join(
        str([x, reverse[x]]).strip("[]").replace("[" ,'').replace(",", "'\t'")
        + '\n'))
```

Any ideas? Python 3 or higher only.

Comment: for the reverse one i get the '   ' around my keys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it:

```
 with open("data1.txt","w") as f:
    for season in d:
        f.write("Sports played in {0}\n".format(season))
        for sp in d[season]:
            f.write(sp+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does everything you requested. It should work with Python 3 if you remove or comment-out the indicated line, however I haven't actually verified whether that is true. If not, it should be very close.

```
from __future__ import print_function  # remove for Python 3
from collections import defaultdict
import sys

GAP = 4
INDENT = ' ' * 2
TEST = True  # print output rather than write it to files

d = {'fall': ['basketball', 'hockey', 'football'],
     'spring': ['cross country', 'tennis', 'baseball', 'archery'],
     'summer': ['soccer', 'softball', 'archery'] }

def reverse_dict(dct):
    reverse = defaultdict(list)
    for key, vals in list(dct.items()):
        for val in vals:
            reverse[val].append(key)
    return reverse

rev_d = reverse_dict(d)

with open("seasonal_sports.txt", "wt") as output:
    if TEST: output = sys.stdout
    for season in sorted(d):
        print('Sports played in {}:'.format(season), file=output)
        for sport in d[season]:
            print(INDENT+sport, file=output)

with open("sport_seasons.txt", "wt") as output:
    if TEST: output = sys.stdout
    longest = max(list(map(len, rev_d)))
    for sport in sorted(rev_d):
        print('{:<{width}}'.format(sport, width=longest+GAP),
              ', '.join(rev_d[sport]), file=output)
```

Comment: thx for your time and great effort.  a follow up question:

Comment: f.write("{}{:^20}\n".format(x,str(reverse[x]).strip("[]")))  i tried adding a width but it  wont work with {:^20}

Comment: @user1753878: I don't know -- syntactically the statement looks OK. Just saying "it wont work" isn't enough information for me to provide you with additional information or advice. Would need to know things like precisely what went wrong and/or what error message(s) were produced.